# Nearly identical ethnicity inheritance?

Tags: dna, autosomal-dna, ancestry.com, parentage, ethnicity-dna

I did the testing through Ancestry, and according to the Ethnicity Inheritance graph (the donut), my parents have nearly identical proportions of Scottish (30% 27%), Irish (10% and 9%), and England/Northwest European (10% and 14%), which strikes me as highly unlikely given their origin stories.

My mom has done a DNA test, and she’s definitely my mom, but maybe someone else is my dad or am I being needlessly concerned?

Comment: You are being needlessly concerned. Firstly the verdict on Ancestry ethnicity is that it's pretty accurate at the level of "Which continent?". More precise than that - don't place any faith in it. One of the other aspects is that people interpret the numbers as telling them about what they expect to see on their tree. In fact, the contributions to so-called ethnicities can go back centuries into the past. E.g. according to some accounts, the Scots were a people who migrated from Ireland to the Highlands of Scotland and sort of displaced the Picts....

Comment: ... If the above is true, then surely people descended from Scottish Highlanders will have Irish ethnicity in their DNA as well as Scottish. So how are Ancestry justified in splitting Scottish and Irish?